# Converting email string into .csv columns

Tags: string, powershell, csv, type-conversion

I have a giant .txt file full of emails in this format:

`Doe, John L (Male) <JohnD@email.com>; Smith, Jane M (Female) <JaneS@email.com>;`

I wanted to know if there is a way to convert this .txt file into a .csv that will have two columns: one for name and one for email:

**Column 1:**

Doe, John L (Male)

Smith, Jane M (Female)

**Column 2:**

JohnD@email.com

JaneS@email.com

I am a bit overwhelmed as to how to start this, I know the commas in the names make this a bit complicated. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there 1 single line in the text file or is the information split over multiple lines?

Comment: One single line unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of parsing your file to psobject with regex, then just export to CSV as usual.

```
$In = 'Doe, John L (Male) <JohnD@email.com>; Smith, Jane M (Female) <JaneS@email.com>;' #use get-content here
$SplitInput = $In -split ';' | Where-Object {$_ -ne ''} #filter in case of extra ; at start or end as in example

$Users = $SplitInput | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -match '^\s*(?<Name>.*) <(?<Email>.*)>$' | Out-Null
    New-Object PSCustomObject @{
        Name = $Matches.Name
        Email = $Matches.Email
    }
}
```

Details of regex used- https://regexr.com/5rfjq

Answer (score 2):

There is no space in emails so something like this

```
$content = "Doe, John L (Male) <JohnD@email.com>; Smith, Jane M (Female) <JaneS@email.com>;"
$content.Split(";") | % { $_.Trim() } | ? { $_ } | % { 
    $iSpace = $_.LastIndexOf(" "); [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = $_.Substring(0, $iSpace) ; Email = $_.Substring($iSpace+2).TrimEnd(">")
} } | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Result :

```
"Name","Email"
"Doe, John L (Male)","JohnD@email.com"
"Smith, Jane M (Female)","JaneS@email.com"
```

Comment: this works well but leaves the < or > when I run it

Comment: I missed an edit I think because the content was a copy/paste.
I Changed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is probably the easiest way to do it here. The trouble is that formats can vary quite a bit.

```
$EmailAddresses = 'Doe, John L (Male) <JohnD@email.com>; Smith, Jane M (Female) <JaneS@email.com>;'

$EmailAddresses -split ';' |
    Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) } |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '\s*(?<Name>.*?)\s*<(?<Email>.*)>\s*') {
            [PSCustomObject]@{Name = $Matches['Name']; Email = $Matches['Email'] }
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "Unrecognized name and email in '$_'"
        }
    } |
    Export-Csv $ExportFile -NoTypeInformation
```

This should parse your content and create a CSV file with the two columns. It will raise a warning on any entry that it doesn't understand, although it will ignore any entry that is whitespace only.

Here's an explanation of the regex:

```
'\s*(?<Name>.*?)\s*<(?<Email>.*)>\s*'
```

`\s*`: Zero or more whitespace characters
`(?<Name>.*)`: Named capture group 'Name' which has some amount of any characters
`\s*`: Zero or more whitespace characters
`<`: The literal character `<`
`(?<Email>.*)`: Named capture group 'Email' which has some amount of any characters
`>`: The literal character `>`
`\s*`: Zero or more whitespace characters

---

Another option would be to split the strings and convert each one to a `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress` which has a properties for Address and DisplayName. That may work the best, but the last time I tried it I ran into trouble. Unfortunately, I don't remember what the trouble was. I think it was commas in display names somehow being improper.

Comment: Another great Regex example, I appreciate the breakdown and added warning feature. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
# Get file contents as string
$fileContents = Get-Content -Path .\sample.txt -Raw

# Split on ; to get each user
# Remove empty entries and trim also
$users = $fileContents.Split(';', [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries).Trim()

# Export each user to CSV file inside this scriptblock
& {
    foreach ($user in $users) {

        # Get index of last space
        $splitIndex = $user.LastIndexOf(' ')
    
        # Create PSCustomObject with Name and Email
        # We can substring this with above split index
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $user.Substring(0, $splitIndex).Trim()
            Email = $user.Substring($splitIndex + 1).Trim('<', '>')
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path .\sample.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Output

```
"Name","Email"
"Doe, John L (Male)","JohnD@email.com"
"Smith, Jane M (Female)","JaneS@email.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran the following provided by @Bacon Bits:

```
$content = Get-content -Path 'C:\.....txt'

$content -split ';' |
    Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) } |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '\s*(?<Name>.*?)\s*<(?<Email>.*)>\s*') {
            [PSCustomObject]@{Name = $Matches['Name']; Email = $Matches['Email'] }
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "Unrecognized name and email in '$_'"
        }
    } | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\.....csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of great answers. I'd like to add another option

```
$content = "Doe, John L (Male) <JohnD@email.com>; Smith, Jane M (Female) <JaneS@email.com>;"

switch -Regex ($content -split ';'){
    '\s?(.+)\s<(.+)>' {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name  = $Matches.1
            Email = $Matches.2
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
Name                   Email          
----                   -----          
Doe, John L (Male)     JohnD@email.com
Smith, Jane M (Female) JaneS@email.com
```

To export csv just capture the output to a variable or you can surround it with a subexpression and then pipe

```
$content = "Doe, John L (Male) <JohnD@email.com>; Smith, Jane M (Female) <JaneS@email.com>;"

$output = switch -Regex ($content -split ';'){
    '\s?(.+)\s<(.+)>' {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name  = $Matches.1
            Email = $Matches.2
        }
    }
}

$output | Export-Csv $outputfile -NoTypeInformation
```

or

```
$content = "Doe, John L (Male) <JohnD@email.com>; Smith, Jane M (Female) <JaneS@email.com>;"

$(switch -Regex ($content -split ';'){
    '\s?(.+)\s<(.+)>' {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name  = $Matches.1
            Email = $Matches.2
        }
    }
}) | Export-Csv $outputfile -NoTypeInformation
```